# how to finish previous page when press the button

Tags: android, button, android-activity

if every page have one button to go to home page how to end previous page because when I press home button and then press back button I want to exit the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your home activity, which I'm assuming is presented when the home button is clicked from somewhere else in the app, you can catch the back button press and exit the app.  The following will show a dialog asking if the user really wants to exit.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        showDialog(DIALOG_REALLY_EXIT_ID);

    return false;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    final Dialog dialog;

    switch(id)
    {
        case DIALOG_REALLY_EXIT_ID:
            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Home.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).create();
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
    }

    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: I try to do like your suggest but when I press back button ,it happen the dialog and after I click Yes it still show the previous page. What should I do?

Comment: In place of "Home.this.finish()" did you replace Home with the name of your "home" activity?

Comment: yes I already replace Home with the name of my "home" activity but it still show the previous page

Comment: Try to replace that line with: "moveTaskToBack(true);"

Comment: thanks now it's can exit program but it still show at "Active application" seem it doesn't finish Can you fix this situation?

Comment: Ok I got it I use "home.this.finish();" and at the other page which have home button I use homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     finish();